# MySQL Syntax Error INSERT INTO and WHERE statements

Tags: java, mysql, syntax-error

I have created a database table with 4 columns

```
user , password , ipaddress , isVIP
```

I would like to insert the data to ipaddress where user = ? and password =?

I tried using this mySQL syntax

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO login(ipaddress) VALUES(?) select * from login where user=? and password=?");
        ps.setString(1,ipaddress);
        ps.setString(2,id);
        ps.setString(3, password);
```

Which it tells me that I have syntax error.

Comment: I think you look for `INSERT INTO login(ipaddress, user, password) values(?,?,?)`

Comment: Required reading: [Best way to store password in database](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1054022/335858).

Comment: @e4c5 yes I did. It solves the problem

Comment: Glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `INSERT` is not syntactically correct. Even when you fix it your `INSERT` will not work because you are selecting and inserting into the same table! That is not allowed in mysql.

You will need to use an update instead.

```
con.prepareStatement("UPDATE login SET ipaddress = ? WHERE user=? and password=?");
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try with below one.

```
 PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO login(ipaddress) VALUES select ipaddress from login where user=? and password=?");
            ps.setString(1,id);
            ps.setString(2, password);
```